# How can I change the apparent type to a real type in Java?

Tags: java

for example :

```
public static String s(Object o)
    return o;
```

this method doesn't work/compile. To solve it I can write `return o.toString()` but I don't want that. I want to change the apparent type of o which is Object to the real type of o which is I know it is String.
How can I do that? I know there is a command that I can use it but I forget it. Anyone know it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just after a cast:

```
public static String castToString(Object o) {
    return (String) o;
}
```

This will throw a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) if `o` is a non-null reference to a non-String type. (If `o` *is* a null reference, the cast will succeed and the result will still be a null reference.)

See [JLS section 5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) for more details.

Comment: what if Object was an interface?

Comment: @user93765: So long as it's *possible* for the conversion to succeed, it should compile fine. Why not just try it?

Comment: this was just an example, my main problem is if I have an interface Action not Object.

Comment: @user93765: Again: why not just try it? In this case a cast to `String` *couldn't* be valid, as `String` doesn't implement an `Action` interface. It helps if you make your sample code representative of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I post my problem in another question? Or here?

Comment: @user93765: Well it's still not clear whether my answer actually solves your problem. We now know that the "source" type is an `Action` interface from somewhere, but we don't know what your "target" type is, and it's not clear whether or not you've actually tried the equivalent of this answer, but using your actual types...

Comment: @user93765: Well that gives us *no* clue as to the way in which it doesn't work. We still don't know what you're really trying to cast to, or whether it compiled but failed at execution time, or whether it didn't compile. It's very hard (and immensely frustrating) to help you when you're providing information one *tiny* bit at a time.

Comment: public class ForLoop implements Action {  
public int index;
public void add(Action a) {
  (ForLoop)a.index++;
}

Comment: @user93765: That's probably a matter of precedence - you probably want `((ForLoop)a).index++;` - or better, split it into two statements: `ForLoop fl = (ForLoop) a; fl.index++;` That's much better for readability. But *please* learn from this experience how to ask decent questions. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your Object to String:

```
public static String castToString(Object o) {
    return (String) o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that  `Object` is in fact a `String` then you can simply typecast.

```
public static String s(Object o)
{
   return (String)o; 
}
```

Comment: what if Object was an interface?

Comment: As long as cast is valid there should not be any problem.